# tracing GCP PubSub MessageID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

So after publishing to a pubsub topic I get response with message ID that have been published:

```
{
  "messageIds": [
    "6113243608857025"
  ]
}
```

How would trace what happened with this messageId afterwards:
a) I want to know did message with this messageID reach specific subscriber - how do I do that?
b) I want to know did message with this messageID reach BQ (in case subscriber has `BigQuery` delivery type) - how do I find out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery subscriptions can be configured to write the Pub/Sub message metadata.  This include the messageId.

Your BigQuery table schema must include the `message_id` column along with other metadata columns.

With those columns included in your BigQuery table schema and the **Write metadata** option enabled, the Pub/Sub messages should persist in the BigQuery table with the associated Pub/Sub messageId.

See https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#properties_subscription for complete details.

Comment: Thanks, Brent! Yes right, have totally forgot about this!
Am marking an answer as accepted, yet if you (or anyone else) have an idea on a) part of the question, kindly please share. I.e. I have messageID, it's not in Bigquery, and I want to find out wether it got stock in pubsubTopic->pubsubSubscription or pubsubSubscription->Bigquery - what do I do?